# How can I have a cell array in Julia?

Tags: julia

Does a cell array exist in Julia? I want an array which its elements are vector or matrix. 
for example `A={1,[2 3],[5 6;7 8];"salam", [1 2 3 4],magic(5)}`.

if you don't mind please help me.

Comment: Arrays can store any type in Julia. There is nothing special about an array of floats. So just use the usual array building syntax, eg `A = [1, [1,2], [1 2 ; 3 4], "salam"]` to allocate values. A word of advice: it sounds likes you are entering Julia with the mindset of "how can I make it do what I do in Matlab?". In the long run, you'll do much better learning Julia, rather than trying to duplicate Matlab in Julia. I recommend having a read of at least the first few chapters of the docs, if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks very much I will do surely . but I only want to use these types in Julia and I couldn't find them. therefore I asked :(. 
`A = [1, [1,2], [1 2 ; 3 4], "salam"]` is not a cell array.

Comment: Unless MatLab has changed drastically in the last few years, what I've written is most definitely functionally equivalent to a MatLab cell array (except the Julia Array type is more flexible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A cell array is a data type with indexed data containers called cells, where each cell can contain **any** type of data

In Julia, arrays can contain values of  homogeneous (`[1, 2, 3]`) or heterogeneous types (`[1, 2.5, "3"]`). Julia will try to promote the values to a common concrete type by default. If Julia can not promote the types contained, the resulting array would be of the abstract type **`Any`**.

Example ported from [Access Data in Cell Array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-cell-array.html), using Julia 1.0.3:

```
julia> C = ["one" "two" "three";  # Matrix literal
                  1     2     3      ]
2×3 Array{Any,2}:
  "one"   "two"   "three"
 1       2       3     

julia> upperLeft = C[1:2,1:2]  # slicing
2×2 Array{Any,2}:
  "one"   "two"
 1       2     

julia> C[1,1:3] = ["first","second","third"]  # slice assignment
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "first" 
 "second"
 "third" 

julia> C
2×3 Array{Any,2}:
  "first"   "second"   "third"
 1         2          3   

julia> numericCells = C[2,1:3]
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 1
 2
 3

julia> last = C[2,3]  # indexing
3

julia> C[2,3] = 300  # indexing assignment
300

julia> C
2×3 Array{Any,2}:
  "first"   "second"     "third"
 1         2          300    

julia> r1c1, r2c1, r1c2, r2c2 = C[1:2,1:2]  # destructuring
2×2 Array{Any,2}:
  "first"   "second"
 1         2       

julia> r1c1
"first"

julia> r2c1
1

julia> r1c2
"second"

julia> r2c2
2

julia> nums = C[2,:]
3-element Array{Any,1}:
   1
   2
 300
```

Example ported from [Combining Cell Arrays with Non-Cell Arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/combining-cell-arrays-with-non-cell-arrays.html):

Notice the use of the **splice** operator (`...`) to incorporate the values of the inner array into the outer one, and the usage of the `Any[]` syntax to prevent Julia from promoting the `UInt8` to an `Int`.

```
julia> A = [100, Any[UInt8(200), 300]..., "Julia"]
4-element Array{Any,1}:
  100       
 0xc8       
  300       
     "Julia"
```

The `.(` broadcast syntax, applies the function `typeof` element wise.

```
julia> typeof.(A)
4-element Array{DataType,1}:
 Int64 
 UInt8 
 Int64 
 String
```

So in summary Julia doesn't need cell arrays, it uses parametric n-dimensional arrays instead. Also Julia only uses brackets for both slicing and indexing (`A[n]`, `A[i, j]`, `A[a:b, x:y]`), parenthesis after a variable symbol is reserved for function calls (`foo()`, `foo(args...)`, `foo(bar = "baz")`).

Comment: I am very appreciated with  your  all helps.

Answer (score 5):

An `Array{Any}` is equivalent to a MATLAB cell array. You can put anything in there. `["hi",:bye,10]`. `a = Array{Any}(undef,5)` builds an uninitialized one, you can `a[1] = ...` to modify values, `push!(a,...)` to increase its length, etc.

Comment: That's slightly inaccurate; `a` isn't actually empty, since it has length 5, but holds undefined values.